# django-grappelli and django-brookie together cause the items for invoice and quote not to total up automatically

Tags: javascript, django, django-grappelli

I have a very specific problem.
I had a django project which was running the application [django-brookie](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-brookie).
Everything worked fine.
I have since added [django-grappelli](http://code.google.com/p/django-grappelli/) to my project and everything works except for one small thing.

If you create a new invoice or quote it should total up the amount in your currency automatically. This is not working anymore and I really can't figure out why. Perhaps something with brookie's javascript clashing with grappelli's javascript?

Any suggestions welcome and if you need more info just ask.

Here is a screenshot of the items. When I place time in minutes it totals up without grappelli:[image]

Here you can see when I put in my time it doesn't total up anything. This has grappelli as you can see in the screenshot:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pinda a developer on the [django-brookie](http://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-brookie) very kindly helped me out. The update to the brookie.js file will now fix that problem for whoever wants to have django-grappelli and django-brookie running together.

Currently you have to do a git clone or pull to get the changes.